# How to use Behaviors.canonicalize in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

I am doing an exercise in Reactive Programming course which requires students to decorate an Typed Actor Behavior to support stash unhandled message. This is the program I wrote so far.

```
package protocols

import akka.actor.typed.Behavior
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl._

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object SelectiveReceive {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](bufferCapacity: Int, initialBehavior: Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] =
    Behaviors.withStash(bufferCapacity) { buffer =>
      Behaviors.setup[T] { ctx =>
        intercept(bufferCapacity, buffer, initialBehavior)
      }
    }

  /**
   * @return A behavior that interprets the incoming messages with the supplied `started`
   *         behavior to compute the next behavior. If the message has been unhandled, it
   *         is stashed in the `buffer`. If the message has been handled, the previously
   *         stashed messages are also sent to the next behavior.
   *
   * @param bufferSize Capacity of the StashBuffer
   * @param buffer     Buffer to stash unhandled messages to
   * @param started    Behavior to decorate. Must be a valid “initial” behavior.
   * @tparam T         Type of messages
   *
   * Hints: Use [[Behavior.interpretMessage]] to compute the next behavior.
   *        Use [[Behavior.isUnhandled]] to know if the message was unhandled by the behavior.
   *        Use [[Behavior.canonicalize]] to make the next behavior applicable to the
   *        `unstashAll` operation of the `StashBuffer` (otherwise, an
   *        `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown by the actor system).
   */
  private def intercept[T: ClassTag](bufferSize: Int, buffer: StashBuffer[T], started: Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] =
    Behaviors.receive { case (ctx, message) =>
      // If the next behavior does not handle the incoming `message`, stash the `message` and
      // return an unchanged behavior. Otherwise, return a behavior resulting from
      // “unstash-ing” all the stashed messages to the next behavior wrapped in an `SelectiveReceive`
      // interceptor.
      val nextBehavior = Behavior.interpretMessage(started, ctx, message)
      if (Behavior.isUnhandled(nextBehavior)) {
        if (buffer.size == bufferSize) {
          throw new StashOverflowException("stash overflow")
        } else {
          buffer.stash(message)
          Behaviors.same
        }
      } else {
        //SelectiveReceive(bufferSize, buffer.unstashAll(Behavior.canonicalize(nextBehavior, started, ctx)))
        val current = intercept(bufferSize, buffer, started)
        val next = SelectiveReceive(bufferSize, nextBehavior)
        val canonicalizeNextBehavior = Behavior.canonicalize(next, current, ctx)
        SelectiveReceive(bufferSize, buffer.unstashAll(canonicalizeNextBehavior))
      }
    }

}
```

In the hint they said to use `canonicalize` method to avoid an exception But I have try multiple way to use this funcion in the code and cannot find a way to avoid that. So I want to ask that what is the use case of canonnicalize method of a Behavior? And how to use this method in the above code.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation seems to work.

```
object SelectiveReceive {
  def apply[T: ClassTag](bufferCapacity: Int, initialBehavior: Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] ={
    Behaviors.withStash[T](bufferCapacity){ buffer =>
      intercept(bufferCapacity, buffer, Behavior.validateAsInitial(initialBehavior))
    }
  }

private def intercept[T: ClassTag](bufferSize: Int, buffer: StashBuffer[T], started: Behavior[T]): Behavior[T] =
  Behaviors.receive { case (ctx, message) =>
    val nextBehavior = Behavior.interpretMessage(started, ctx, message)
    if (Behavior.isUnhandled(nextBehavior)) {
      buffer.stash(message)
      Behaviors.same
    } else {
      val nextBehaviorCanonicalized = Behavior.canonicalize(nextBehavior, started, ctx)
      buffer.unstashAll(SelectiveReceive(bufferSize, nextBehaviorCanonicalized))
    }
  }
```

To be honest, I got it working mainly through trial-and-error having found the hints in the homework poorly worded and the Akka documentation (particularly around canonicalize too light). Nonetheless I'll try to talk through my understanding - and hopefully someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Starting by taking the StashBufferDemo.scala example we have

```
val initial = Behaviors.withStash[String](100) { buffer =>
        Behaviors.receiveMessage {
            case "first" =>
                buffer.unstashAll(running)
            case other =>
                buffer.stash(other)
                Behaviors.same
        }
    }

val running = Behaviors.receiveMessage[String] { msg =>
        println(s"Hello $msg!")
        if (msg == "stop") Behaviors.stopped else Behaviors.same
    }
```

The key motivation for canonicalize is so that the apply method of SelectiveReceive can pass the validateAsInitial method as mentioned in the hints (your implementation needs to add this). The reason why we didn't need canonicalize in the StashBufferDemo.scala example is that we just had running which is just a Behaviors.receiveMessage whereas in SelectiveReceive.scala we have an initialisation of a buffer which cannot start with an initialBehavior that is Same (or Unhandled - but it shouldn't be this because we only initialize a new SelectiveReceive if Behavior.isUnhandled is false). My understanding of canonicalize is it is just a way to figure out, if you have a Behavior.same with what the Behavior actually is. We can see this in the source code where we have https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/Behavior.scala

```
@tailrec
  def canonicalize[T](behavior: Behavior[T], current: Behavior[T], ctx: TypedActorContext[T]): Behavior[T] =
    (behavior._tag: @switch) match {
      case BehaviorTags.SameBehavior      => current
      case BehaviorTags.UnhandledBehavior => current
      case BehaviorTags.DeferredBehavior =>
        val deferred = behavior.asInstanceOf[DeferredBehavior[T]]
        canonicalize(deferred(ctx), deferred, ctx)
      case _ => behavior
    }
```

which just simply replaces Same with current (i.e. the previous Behavior).

So then re: buffer.unstashAll we want to unstash all the messages in the buffer which is basically just a tail recursive way to interpretOne message at a time, generating the output Behavior from that message which becomes an input for the next and so on (see unstash and interpretOne https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor-typed/src/main/scala/akka/actor/typed/internal/StashBufferImpl.scala) to our new SelectiveReceive. This however, needs to be initialized with the canonicalized nextBehavior just in case nextBehavior is Behavior.same

You approach I think gets the error as you try to canonicalize for the unstashAll method (which I think does not care about Behaviors.same) and not for the SelectiveReceive method which does

Comment: The body of _canonicalize_() is a great example of inadequate or inappropriate variable naming,  to me. If the first parameter is named 'targetBehvior', then the function becomes kind of self explanatory. The fact that the 'current' is essentially the 'previous' behaviour, stated automatically and clearly.